# Visual Studio auto alignment

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm using VS 2019 and I code in C++
Is it possible to align all or selected code like this? Like plugin or something
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw4Up.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any plugins simply you can just use the Tab button on your keyboard.

Comment: It is not smart way, I know this!